# Wakelock.release is not a function. How to release screenlock, non mobile

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript on Windows Chrome.

I can successfully set a wakelock and have tested that it does, in fact, prevent my screen from going dark. However, I'm not able to release it. The error I get is

wakeLock.release is not a function

I've also tried putting the release code in an async function and using await.

```
async function set_wakelock() {
    wakeLock = await navigator.wakeLock.request('screen');
    return wakeLock;
}

var wakeLock = set_wakelock();

// alert(wakeLock);  // Correctly shows [Object promise]

try {
    wakeLock.release();
    wakeLock = null;
}  catch (err) {
    alert(err); // wakeLock.release is not a function
}
```

Comment: `set_wakelock()` is an `async` function, but you are not awaiting it in `var wakeLock = set_wakelock()`. Thus your `wakeLock` is not a [`WakeLockSentinel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WakeLockSentinel) but a `Promise<WakeLockSentinel>` and as [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)  don't have a `release` method, that's the error you are seeing ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You can either do `var wakeLock = await set_wakelock()` (but you would have to be in an `async` context for this) or `wakeLock.then(wls => wls.release())`

Comment: wakeLock.then(wls => wls.release()) did the trick. Thank you! I'll mark it as correct if you put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @derpirscher's comment, I needed to call release() a different way.

```
async function set_wakelock() {
    wakeLock = await navigator.wakeLock.request('screen');
    // optional listener:
    wakeLock.addEventListener('release', () => {
         alert('Wake Lock was released');
    }); 
    return wakeLock;
}

function release_wakelock(){
    if  (! wakeLock){
        return;
    }
    try {
        wakeLock.then(wls => wls.release())
        wakeLock = null;
    }  catch (err) {
        // alert(err);
    }
}

var wakeLock = null;
wakeLock =  set_wakelock();
release_wakelock();

// note: should first check that navigator.wakeLock is supported by the browser.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `set_wakelock` is an async method, therefore the immediate return is a promise. Change your code to await for the result

```
var wakeLock = await set_wakelock();
```

Something like:

```
async function set_wakelock() {
  wakeLock = await navigator.wakeLock.request('screen');
  return wakeLock;
}

var wakeLock = await set_wakelock();

// Use the wakelock here...

// Release the wakelock after you have finished using it
await wakeLock.release();
wakeLock = null;
```

Comment: The set_wakelock() code works as I have it with the await inside the async function. Your way gives an error "await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"